# Dockerの構成とそれに伴うOSの選定に関する質問

Tags: docker

DockerでECSを使ってWebサービスの環境構築を行おうと考えています。
ただDockerの中のOSを何にすれば良いかわからず困っています。

と言いますのも、Dockerの一般的な構築はサービス毎にDockerを個別に立てるのが一般的と聞きました。
そうなるとまずDockerをまとめるDockerがおり、その中に役割毎のDocker(サーバ、DB...)を立てるのかと想像しました。
だとすると役割毎に立てるDockerのOSを一般的なLinuxOS(CentOSなど)にしてしまうと、OSの容量だけでもかなり増えてしまいそうです。
その問題を解決するためにCoreOSというOSが存在することを知りました。

そうなると疑問点があります。
このDockerをまとめるDockerもCoreOSにするべきなんでしょうか？
また今まで自分が書いた想定は一般的なのでしょうか？

ご回答いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらくですが、質問者様は、いわゆるマイクロサービスアーキテクチャを docker で実装する話をしているのだと思います。さらには、あるフロントエンド用のサービス(html のレンダリングなどは、ここでやる想定)があって、そのサービスがバックエンドサービスと通信を行い、ウェブアプリケーションとして動作させる形態を想像しているのだと思います。

またその際に、バックエンドの docker は、フロントエンドのサーバー (docker) の中で立ち上げることも想定しているのかなと思っています。

仮にそうだったとした場合、一つ重要な点は、 フロント用サービスと、バックエンドのサービスは、基本的に独立したサーバーとして運用する構成にするのが通常である、という点です。

docker でフロントとバックエンドのサーバーを分けた場合、それらは同じ階層の docker として運用し、一方(フロント) がもう一方(バックエンド) に通信を行いに行く、という構成になると思います。

わかりやすいのは、 docker-compose にバックエンドとフロントエンド、それらをつなぐポート情報を記述するようなイメージでしょうか。

こういった構成をとった場合、フロントとバックエンドのベースイメージは、基本的になんでもいいはずです。重要なのは、コンテナの expose しているポートに通信すると、正しく期待した動作をコンテナがしてくれることです。

さらに注釈を加えると、 docker の中で docker を使うのは、やめたほうがいいと思います。docker の unix socket をコンテナの中に埋め込むような方法などで、コンテナの中からでも docker を使えるように設定できなくはないですが、マウントの解決がやたら面倒になった記憶があります。

Comment: すみません、確かに前提環境を書いておくべきでした。
またYukiさんの想定通りです、ありがとうございます。
またフロントとバックは分けるべきというお話も確かにその通りでした。
とりあえずフロントとバックはそれぞれDockerにしようと思います。
そして、今後バックの中でも更にサーバを分けるという話になればその時にまたDockerを個別に立てていこうと思います。
ご回答ありがとうございました。